# Facebook SDK and OAuth 2.0 - working with the token in JavaScript and redirection

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

When coming back from the Facebook JS SDK login() call I get a cookie set on my side as:
ex. (I've changed the characters some)

`fbsr_17066472650000: edmYrII1FpD8TfeBCDcgO5ri0aRDFfh5e4efESdXlaU.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUNuVW1aS3A4U3p0a0RmNzhLR1FwTE5wSHpasdfafdasdfaVnVfOWo3c01oUFRaYVhjR3FTUFRFRHJrX2Ezasdfadadfasfasfda5ZektURV9xQWxaREV1WlVVZ2hFcDJTVVc4ZVB6d2tmRTVhRHY0RXpRdVhFa0xMd3hKS3gxckMyV1Y4aks1cmtNSHFWZVBaMWpQQklrQkVORDh4ZWtQd0pxUDlLYmMiLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzMjQ0ODUwNjksInVzZXJfaWQiOiI1MTUxNzcxNDcifQ`

Is it correct to say that this string breaks down as:

```
fbsr_{appId}:{token}
```

Is this the real token? or do I need to encrypt/decrypt something?

Lastly, how can I redirect to another page after the login using something like:

```
window.location.href='foo.php';
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I get this back in my server-side decrypt process. It doesn't seem correct. Or is this what I should expect? (note: I changed some of the data slightly)

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256",
  "code":"AQDnemhHwRHAv1pSI2TjKkO4x36GasdfadfasfdQKJn6Sqh8qgJNnCtzA5C41Y5TvRIp94BWQNTprLVyc4PHmYCPG0jOxkUpJ3RnviYW3p-f9lbWn32qkv7NZv-8T42j6_X3l4IMjH-Nthh7LAIaiy8YradJmRzXQwaKpDP5TP6JssrMFbHYYnRrMA",
"issued_at":1324491454,
"user_id":"515100000"}
```

Comment: it's actually breaks as `fbsr_{appId}:{signature}.{encoded_session}`

Comment: The `signed_request` data in your update is ok, did you expected anything other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call token is actually a [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which is encoded session details for user.

And the redirection you want after user is logged in can be triggered by providing `redirect_uri` argument of Facebook [Login Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) url.

For more info read [Facebook Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

While you need to do decryption on the `signed_request` on the server side ([PHP-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) can be used for this) on the client side it's not really needed if you using Facebook [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) which provides [`FB.getAuthResponse`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/) and [`FB.getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to get user session details.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question. But why couldn't or shouldn't you decrypt the signed request in the JavaScript? I'm working on a framework right now, Grails which has no working server-side decryption as of 12/21/2011. I'm trying to find a work-around because my site is currently offline w the OAuth2 upgrade.

Comment: I do need my server to be able to ask for your friends list as needed. So I was thinking of just passing whatever my server needed (maybe token) from client-side to server-side.

Comment: ok. think I understand the issue... if I decrypted on the client I would be revealing my appSecret.

Comment: On the client-side you probably already using Facebook JS SDK client which provides other ways to access user session data. You can for sure decode this (it's simply [Base64 Url](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3548#section-4) encoded string but for validation you as you noticed need an `application secret` which should be secret ;) As for the JavaScript there is some solution to do this in JavaScript (again, server-side) like facebook-wrapper middleware for node.js

Comment: what does it mean when I get back the following as my JSON data back from Facebook. This doesn't seem correct. see Update #1 in question itself.

Comment: The problem stemmed from the inclusion of both 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3' and 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4' into the final .war file. There was some change to the Base64 class in 1.4 that allows it to take a boolean on wether it should be urlSafe or not. My understanding is... if you get both included into the war the server is just going to pick one and use it. My code on the server was taking the 1.3 variant everytime.

Comment: seems to be included by oauth and http-client plugins. for now I have added a line to my BuildConfig.groovy to resolve this: 
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete {fileset(dir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib", includes:"commons-codec-1.3.jar")}
}